# How can I generate a tailor-made directed graph from a given matrix

Tags: graphs-and-networks, code-request

Given a matrix `mat`:

```
mat = {{1, 5, 2, 6}, {4, 3, 4, 1}, {0, 1, 4, 0}, {2, 1, 3, 4}};
```

I want to apply the following conditions to generate various directed graphs.

1. Denote columns by A, B, C, D
2. Choose a column, say A (1st column), and find the binary relations between   A and those cells with a number higher than 25% (threshold) of the respective column total. For example, for column A, BA and DA will be selected as the ratios (4/7 and 2/7) will be higher than 25%, respectively.
3. Then choose column B because we obtained BA at step 2 and repeat the same procedure at step 2 to find those relations above 25% of the total of column B; next do the same operation for the second relation obtained in step 2, which is DA.
4. Next, choose column C and follow the same operations in step 2 end so on...
5. Generate a directed graph of all the significant relations obtained from the matrix `mat`.

After completing the visits to all of the columns, then apply the same steps 
(1-4 above) to the transpose of the matrix `mat` to generate another directed graph of the resulting relations.

I want to generate:

1. two directed graphs: one for column-wise operation (`subgraph1`) and another for row-wise operation (`subgraph2`) and
2. another directed graph combining the two directed graphs in (1) with different colors to differentiate the column-wise and row-wise graphs.

I like to produce these directed graphs using a function `f[mat,th,column#]` for automated generation of the directed graphs using `mat` by choosing a specific column (for example, A as column#) and a given threshold `th`, and another function `g[subgraph1, subgraph2, column#]`to combine the individual graphs.

**UPDATE**
Below, I update the question with an example explaining the steps for the code development.

Starting node A:

[image]

Starting node B:

[image]

Staring node C:

[image]

Starting node D:

[image]

Comment: Please include the actual graph (output) that you expect for the example matrix. This would greatly clarify the question.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon: Yes, indeed. I will update my question with the expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

```
ClearAll[grapH, combinedGraph]
grapH[mat_, dir_: "Column"][t_, v_, opts : OptionsPattern[Graph]] := 
    Module[{vertices = CharacterRange["A", "Z"][[;; Length@mat]], 
      comp = dir /. {"Column" -> VertexInComponent, "Row" -> VertexOutComponent}, 
      gf = dir /. {"Column" -> AdjacencyGraph, "Row" -> ReverseGraph@*AdjacencyGraph}, g}, 
      g = gf[vertices, Transpose[UnitStep[Normalize[#, Total] - t] & /@ Transpose[mat]]];
      Subgraph[g, comp[g, v], opts]];

combinedGraph[mat_, t_, v_, opts : OptionsPattern[Graph]] := 
  Module[{el = EdgeList /@ {grapH[Transpose@mat, "Row"][t, v], grapH[mat][t, v]},
       complement, intersection}, 
    complement = Complement @@ el; 
    intersection = Intersection @@ el; 
    SetProperty[EdgeAdd[grapH[mat][t, v], complement], 
      {EdgeStyle -> {_ :> Blue, 
            Alternatives @@ intersection -> Dashed, 
            Alternatives @@ complement -> Red}, opts}]]
```

**Examples:**

```
mat = {{1, 5, 2, 6}, {4, 3, 4, 1}, {0, 1, 4, 0}, {2, 1, 3, 4}};
vertices = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
vc = Thread[vertices -> GraphEmbedding[GridGraph[{2, 2}]]];  
t = .25;


Row[MapThread[grapH[## & @@ #][.25, "A",   VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", 
      VertexCoordinates -> vc, ImageSize -> {400, 400}, EdgeStyle -> #2, 
      PlotLabel -> Grid[{{"mat", "direction", "threshold", "starting\nnode"}, 
        {MatrixForm[First@#], #[[2]], t, "A"}}, Dividers -> All]] &,
   {{{mat, "Column"}, {Transpose@mat,  "Row"}}, {Blue, Red}}]]
```

[image]

```
Row[MapThread[grapH[## & @@ #][.25, "C",   VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", 
      VertexCoordinates -> vc, ImageSize -> {400, 400}, EdgeStyle -> #2, 
      PlotLabel -> Grid[{{"mat", "direction", "threshold", "starting\nnode"}, 
        {MatrixForm[First@#], #[[2]], t, "C"}}, Dividers -> All]] &,
   {{{mat, "Column"}, {Transpose@mat,  "Row"}}, {Blue, Red}}]]
```

[image]

```
Row[combinedGraph[mat, .25, #, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name", 
        VertexCoordinates -> vc, 
        PlotLabel -> Grid[{{"threshold : ", .25}, {"starting node: ", #}}], 
        ImageSize -> 200] & /@ {"A", "B", "C", "D"}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[grph]
grph[mat_, t_, v_, opts : OptionsPattern[Graph]] := 
  Module[{vertices = CharacterRange["A", "Z"][[;; Length@mat]], assoc, edges, g},
   assoc = AssociationThread[vertices, UnitStep[Normalize[#, Total] - t] & /@ 
      Transpose[mat]];
   edges = Join @@ KeyValueMap[Thread[DirectedEdge[#, vertices[[Flatten@#2]]]] &][
      Position[#, 1] & /@ assoc];
   g = Graph[edges];
   Subgraph[g, VertexOutComponent[g, v], VertexLabels -> "Name",  opts]];
```

***Examples:***

Using `mat` and `Transpose @ mat` as the first argument:

```
Row[Panel /@ MapThread[grph[#, .25, "A", ImageSize -> 300, EdgeStyle -> #2, 
     PlotLabel -> MatrixForm[#]] &, {{mat, Transpose@mat}, {Blue, Red}}]]
```

[image]

To show the two graphs for `mat` and `Transpose@mat` together:

```
edgeadd = Complement[EdgeList@grph[Transpose@mat, .25, "A", EdgeStyle -> Red], 
   EdgeList@grph[mat, .25, "A"]];
SetProperty[EdgeAdd[grph[mat, .25, "A"], edgeadd], 
 EdgeStyle -> {_ -> Blue, Alternatives @@ edgeadd -> Red}]
```

[image]

Several combinations of thresholds and starting nodes:

```
Grid[Outer[ grph[mat, #, #2, ImageSize -> 200, 
    PlotLabel -> Grid[{{"threshold :", #}, {"starting node : ", #2}}]] &,
 {.1, .25, .3}, {"A", "B", "C"}], Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Very very nice...Now I will try to digest your heavy code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: When we combine two separate graphs, I lose track of the information on the edges that are present in both graphs. Would it possible to indicate with dashed lines those edges appearing in both graphs at the same time?

Comment: @TugrulTemel, re "edges appearing in both graphs", you can use `complement = 
  Complement[
   EdgeList@grph[Transpose@mat, .25, "A", EdgeStyle -> Red], 
   EdgeList@grph[mat, .25, "A"]];
intersection = 
  Intersection[
   EdgeList@grph[Transpose@mat, .25, "A", EdgeStyle -> Red], 
   EdgeList@grph[mat, .25, "A"]];
SetProperty[EdgeAdd[grph[mat, .25, "A"], edgeadd], 
 EdgeStyle -> {_ :> Blue, Alternatives @@ intersection -> Dashed, 
   Alternatives @@ complement -> Red}]`. Re direction of the edge b/w "C" and "B", it is more likely that _I_ missed/misunderstood something.

Comment: I checked all the cases (A, B, C, D). Except for case C, other graphs (number and direction of the edges) all are correct in your code. As mentioned earlier, in  case of C with original matrix `mat`, the direction of edge from C to B in your  code should be from B to C.This is the only contradiction I have. I should try the code with another example to see if the same contradiction remains.

Comment: I checked it with another example and found that the function`grph[...]` has a problem, possibly `Associations` is problematic. In my second example, directions of most edges using the original matrix (without transposing) are wrong, while the vertices selected are correct.

Comment: I am not sure if the `codes` for the examples are bug free. They do not produce any graph nor give any error message. It simply declares the code itself as output. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: @Tugrul, I think it is because  `vertices` is undefined. Fixed now.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I can now generate exactly the same output as you have above. This is really a very useful code for my research on "supply chains". Surely, I will refer to you for this contribution. Thanks again.

Comment: In my original graph, I have 17 vertices and if I revise `vc = Thread[vertices -> GraphEmbedding[GridGraph[{4, 4}]]];` it works with one less vertex. How do you revise `GraphEmbedding` if the number of vertices is odd?

Comment: @Tugrul, maybe you can try `vc = Thread[vertices -> GraphEmbedding[GridGraph[{4, 5}]]][[;;Length[vertices]]]`?

Comment: Your suggestion gave the same error; but then, I adjusted your suggestion using `Drop[...]` so as to make the vertices compatible with `GridGraph` size.  `vc = Thread[
   vertices -> 
    Drop[GraphEmbedding[GridGraph[{4, 5}]], -3][[;; 
       Length[vertices]]]]; `, which works fine now. I solved the problem with your guidance. Thank you.

Comment: I had a misplaced `]`; the correct form is `vc = Thread[vertices -> 
  GraphEmbedding[GridGraph[{4, 5}]][[;; Length[vertices]]]]`.

Comment: Thank you very much for letting me know the correct form, which is much simpler than my revision.

Comment: We use `mat` and `Transpose[mat]` as two inputs. If I want to use a totally different matrix `mat1`, for example, instead of `Transpose[mat]`, should I simply replace `Transpose[mat]` in your code with `mat1`?

Comment: @TugrulTemel,  right.

Comment: I tried to use `PlotLegend` in the above graphs with three types of lines: red, blue, and dashed blue. How can I place `PlotLegends`below a graph (one of the above graphs with 3 edge types) to specify the types of edges?

Comment: @Tugrul you can try something like `edges = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1};
estyles = {Red, Blue, Directive[Blue, Dashed]};
Legended[Graph[edges, EdgeStyle -> Thread[edges -> estyles]], 
 Placed[LineLegend[estyles, edges, LegendLayout -> "Row"], Below]]`

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt answer.

Comment: I submitted a short paper for publication, and footnote 4 on page 4 refers to your Code above. I hope the way I cited your contribution is fine with you. I wanted to send you a copy of the paper but I do not know how to send it. If you let me know, I will send you the paper.

Comment: @Tugrul Bey, thank you so much for the citation -- it is a great pleasure to know something I scribbled turned out to be useful. You can post a comment here when a link to the paper is available.

Comment: I will post here the link to the paper when published. Cok cok tesekkurler...